# Parsing JSON Object within an Object java

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Am trying to map this json with `volley`. But I keep getting an error inside my constructor each time.

```
[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "time_created": {
            "date": "2018-09-18 09:24:34.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "America/Chicago"
        },
]
```

So I need to fetch the time_created object. This is my model class;
public class NeighbourhoodOther implements  Serializable{

```
    public int id;
    public TimeCreated timeCreated;
 public NeighbourhoodOther(){

    }
    public NeighbourhoodOther(int id, TimeCreated timeCreated ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.timeCreated= time_created;
       }

    public TimeCreated getTimeCreated() {
        return timeCreated;
    }

    public void setTimeCreated(TimeCreated timeCreated) {
        this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public static class TimeCreated {
        public String timezone;
        public int timezoneType;
        public String date;

        public String getTimezone() {
            return timezone;
        }

        public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
            this.timezone = timezone;
        }

        public int getTimezoneType() {
            return timezoneType;
        }

        public void setTimezoneType(int timezoneType) {
            this.timezoneType = timezoneType;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the way am trying to fetch with volley but I get an error each time.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < neighOther.length(); i++) {


                            JSONObject neighOtherObject = neighOther.getJSONObject(i);
                                int id = neighOtherObject.getInt("id");
                          
                           
                           NeighbourhoodOther.TimeCreated timeCreated = neighOtherObject.getJSONObject("time_created");
                              

                                NeighbourhoodOther neighbourhoodOther = new NeighbourhoodOther(id, time_created);
                               otherNeighbourHoodList.add(neighbourhoodOther);

}
```

The error inside my constructor says its expecting a JSONObject instead of `TimeCreated`. Whats the best way to fetch the data. I need to pass the `date` String to a `TextView`.

Comment: Could you provide error log?

Comment: my constructor says a JSONObject is expected instead of a TimeCreated object

Comment: but I need to fetch the TimeCreated object so I could se its fields. Do you get?

Comment: NeighbourhoodOther.TimeCreated timeCreated = neighOtherObject.getJSONObject("time_created"); this line throws the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NeighbourhoodOther.TimeCreated timeCreated = neighOtherObject.getJSONObject("time_created")` returns a `JSONObject` not `NeighbourhoodOther.TimeCreated`

try:

```
JSONObject obj = neighOtherObject.getJSONObject("time_created");
NeighbourhoodOther.TimeCreated temp = new NeighbourhoodOther.TimeCreated()
temp.timezone = obj.getString("timezone");
... fill in NeighbourhoodOther.TimeCreated members
```

Answer (score 0):

[getJSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)) return a jsonobject, so you should cast it to custom type.
There are lots of libray to do this, `Gson` is the one.

```
    import com.google.gson.Gson; 
    
    //other stuffs

    Gson gson= new Gson();

    TimeCreated obj = gson.fromJson(neighOtherObject.getJSONObject("time_created").toString(), TimeCreated.class);
```